# Why is $x(\log(x)-1)+1\geq \frac{1}{4}(x-1)^2$ in a neighborhood of $x=1$?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

In https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.2952.pdf they say on p. 25 that $x(\log(x)-1)+1\geq \frac{1}{5}(x-1)^2$ in a neighborhood of $x=1$.  In another paper that I don't have the link to they say that it's $x(\log(x)-1)+1\geq \frac{1}{4}(x-1)^2$ and it follows from a Taylor expansion.  I can't figure out why.

Comment: If you differentiate the function $f(x) = x(\log(x)-1)+1-\frac{1}{4}(x-1)^2$ twice and substitute $1$, you will find that $1$ is a local minima for this function. Thus the inequality holds locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a Taylor series expansion around $1$, we have
$$
x(\log x - 1)+1  = \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 + o((x-1)^2))
$$
Put differently,
$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x(\log x - 1)+1}{(x-1)^2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
so that, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\frac{x(\log x - 1)+1}{(x-1)^2} > \frac{1}{2} - \varepsilon
$$
as long as $|x-1|< \delta$. This implies both statements you mention.

Comment: Can you show how you do that Taylor series expansion?  I am getting something different using https://math.stackexchange.com/a/585189/56922.  In particular I don't have the $\frac{1}{2}$ coefficient and .

Comment: @mlstudent Are you sure you are doing it for $x$ around $1$, not $0$? A good way to proceed is to set $h=x-1$ (so that $h\to0$) and do the Taylor expansion of $$(1+h)(\log(1+h)-1)+1$$ for $h$ around $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x(\ln x-1)+1-\frac{1}{4}(x-1)^2$. Then,

$$f(x)=(1+t)\ln(1+t)-t-\frac14t^2$$

where $t=x-1$. Taylor expand $\ln(1+t) = t -\frac12t^2$ to express $f(x)$ around $t= 0$,

$$f(x) = (1+t)(t-\frac12t^2)-t-\frac14t^2=\frac14t^2=\frac14(x-1)^2\ge0$$

Thus, in the  neighborhood of $x=1$, $f(x)\ge0$, or

$$x(\ln x-1)+1\ge\frac{1}{4}(x-1)^2$$