# Power series expansion of matrix logarithms

Tags: sequences-and-series, lie-groups, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus

How does one derive the power series expansion for matrix logarithm? Let's suppose we define the matrix exponential in the standard way as a power series.

I'm only interested in matrices so the most general statements involving abstract lie-groups/algebras isn't important to me.

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488730/composition-of-formal-power-series-of-exp-and-log) for formal power series.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3535630/357854) contains series expansions for $\log(X)$ and for $\log(I-X)\;$